# What to use instead of poseAsClass?

Tags: colors, nscolorpanel

How can I call NSColorWell without using poseAsClass? Here is my old code, but poseAsClass is depreciated.

```
+ (void) load
{
    [MyColorWell poseAsClass:[NSColorWell class]];
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of replacing exact functionality of `poseAsClass` with [JRSwizzle](https://github.com/rentzsch/jrswizzle) (a library for overriding methods):

[https://github.com/wakatime/textmate-wakatime@06d6e3684603a07ee2a981823f69868d0f6d1a26](https://github.com/wakatime/textmate-wakatime/commit/06d6e3684603a07ee2a981823f69868d0f6d1a26)